# How to Ping WSDL in Java

Tags: java, wsdl, ping

How can I execute a Ping for my WSDL in Java?

I already tried this:

```
InetAddress.getByname(my_wsdl).isReachable(3000);
```

but didn't work.

Comment: You cannot ping a file. Are you asking how to 'ping' your web service endpoint?

Comment: Are you asking about validating that the service is available? If so, just append `?wsdl` to your service's URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 private boolean isWSDLAvailable(String wsdlAddr) {
        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(wsdlAddr);
            c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            c.getInputStream();
            return c.getResponseCode() == 200;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (c != null) c.disconnect();
        }    
}
```